# Master Detail Nested Way

Tags: asp.net

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and need to design a master detail form like the following.

http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/MasterDetail/MasterDetail.aspx

Any suggestions/free components or solutions which I can use to develop the similar interface?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish the same effect by loading the controls into multiple [`UpdatePanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.aspx) controls that are initially empty in each row of your table.

You would add the controls you need on-demand when the update panel is refreshing.

The DevExpress control is great though, try use this if you have the resources.